# looping file upload form with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

im currently using jquery booklet [Moleskine Notebook with jQuery Booklet](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/12/14/moleskine-notebook/) to make a logbook with some images to be uploaded for every page.
what im doing is im looping the div of every page in php as im calling data from DB, but when i tried to use file upload form as follows , it only works on first page on. the upload button appeared on every other page but it does nothing, not even call the upload window.

every page has its own log_id `$row['log_id']`.

so any solution is much appreciated.

```
if (mysqli_multi_query($conn, $sql)) {
 do {
  if ($result = mysqli_store_result($conn)) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

echo '<div>';
echo '    <form method="post" name="upload_form" id="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="php/multiple_upload.php">';
echo '      <input type="hidden" name="form_submit" value="1"/>';
echo '      <input type="file" class="hidden" name="images[]" id="upload-images" multiple >';
echo '      <input name="log_id" type="hidden" value="'.$row['log_id'].'">' ;
echo '    </form>'; 
echo '</div>' ; 
            }
        mysqli_free_result($result);
        }   
    } while (mysqli_next_result($conn));
}
```

and the here is the script for calling form

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#upload-images').on('change',function(){
    $('#upload_form').ajaxForm({
        beforeSubmit:function(e){
            $('.progress').show();
        },
        success:function(e){
            $('.progress').hide();

                location.reload(true);              
        },
        error:function(e){

            }
        }).submit();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using id `$('#upload_form').ajaxForm({***});`. This will only find and target the first `#upload_form`

And if you're using class like `$('.upload_form').ajaxForm({***});`. This will find and target `all` the form class `.upload_form`

You need to define which `form` you're looking for. In this case, You just need to find the closest/parent of `.upload-images` form. Like below.

Do like this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.upload-images').on('change',function(){
    $(this).closest('form').ajaxForm({ // target the parent form
        beforeSubmit:function(e){
            $('.progress').show();
        },
        success:function(e){
            $('.progress').hide();

                location.reload(true);              
        },
        error:function(e){

            }
        }).submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: would you please explain more, how is this helping my case?

Comment: Check my edit.  I'm sorry if you don't understand my explanation.  English is not my native language.

Comment: that solved the none working buttons, but when i press any one it opens a lot of upload windows not only one.

Comment: I don't think my examples is wrong here. Please check your code. This is my simple example https://jsfiddle.net/synz/7m2thzd2/ . You can try click to upload.